# SQL Server create Triggers on INSERT and Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a table with the following columns: ObservationId, FirstCreatedDate, description, ... ... and LastUpdatedDate in SQL Server 2008 R2. The **ObservationId** is an identity with increment by 1.

I need to create two triggers, one for INSERT and the other for UPDATE. On new record inserted, the INSERT trigger will update FirstCreatedDate column by getting the current datetime; while on existing record updated, the UPDATE trigger will update LastUpdatedDate colunm by getting the current datetime.

I have failed in doing this as I am guessing the identify might be the problem.

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Cheers,
Alex

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_InsertNewObservation] ON [dbo].[GCUR_OBSERVATION] 
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for trigger here
  UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION SET GCUR_OBSERVATION.FirstCreatedDate = getdate()
  FROM GCUR_OBSERVATION a INNER JOIN INSERTED ins ON a.ObservationId = ins.ObservationId

END
```

Comment: did you get any error post it here please!

Comment: It's weird that the code I posted up here worked when I used INSERT sql in the Query Window to add a record while not properly successful when I manually tried to add a new record in the Edit Table mode. The issue is the identify ID field got a red question mark beside; however, when I did a select all query, the record was added.... ps. I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are mostly correct but are not accessing the INSERTED or DELETED tables correctly.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_InsertNewObservation] ON [dbo].[GCUR_OBSERVATION] 
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- get the last id value of the record inserted or updated
  DECLARE @id INT
  SELECT @id = [ObservationId]
  FROM INSERTED

  -- Insert statements for trigger here
  UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION 
  SET GCUR_OBSERVATION.FirstCreatedDate = GETDATE()
  WHERE [ObservationId] = @id 

END
```

PS. Hopefully this works as I wrote it in notepad and haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is for AFTER UPDATE to modify last changed date column.

Please advice if you see any issue with it. Thanks!

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_UpdateObservation] ON [dbo].[GCUR_OBSERVATION] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- get the last id value of the record inserted or updated
DECLARE @id INT
SELECT @id = [ObservationId]
FROM DELETED

-- Insert statements for trigger here
UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION
SET GCUR_OBSERVATION.LastUpdatedDate = getdate()
WHERE [ObservationId] = @id

END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[TrigerName] ON [dbo].[TableCreateTriger] FOR INSERT AS
INSERT INTO TableInsertDate SELECT * FROM TableCreateTriger
```